# Fit NRTL parameters for an immiscible system

Tags: thermodynamics

**Problem description:**

I need to know the liquid-liquid eqilibrium behavior of a THF-water-toluene system. I need to use NRTL because UNIFAC does not predict THF-water systems accurately.

I have NRTL parameters only for THF and water. UNIFAC is predicts THF-toluene, so I could simulate that system with UNIFAC and fit NRTL parameters to the UNIFAC results.

This leaves toluene-water parameters. Since toluene and water are immiscible, VLE data does not exist, only VLLE data or LLE data. I have heard that it requires some special expertise to fit NRTL parameters to LLE data.

**Main question:** How can I fit toluene-water NRTL parameters?

**Related side question:** According to Wikipedia, there can be two sets of NRTL parameters: 1.) for LLE prediction and 2.) for VLE prediction. My thermodynamics textbook doesn't discuss this. To what extent can parameters fit to VLE data be used for LLE? Please link to a reference that discusses this, if you know of one.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter fitting is parameter fitting. What you need is experimental data (often hard to come by), a model (NRTL), an algorithm (method to calculate LLE) and a fitting routine (I recommend something like the Nelder-Mead). If you are using something like `Matlab`, you can just use `fmincon` or one of its many solvers to minimize the error between predicted and experimental by changing the parameters.

You guess initial parameters, use your algorithm to predict LLE, compare the compositions in both phases with the corresponding experimental data, calculate the sum of the errors squared, and then use your fitting routine to calculate new parameters.

The process simulator `VMGSim` is capable of doing this, but it was not openly documented at least a few years ago. I am sure `Aspen/HYSIS` can do this as well. You can always use `Matlab` or another program too, the solvers in `Matlab` or any other package will be good enough.